# What's wrong with my use of if / then in this script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning if and then statements. I'm trying to write code that takes any decimal number input (like 2, 3, or even 5.5) and prints whether the input was even or odd (depending on whether the input is actually an integer.)

I get an error in line 8

```
#input integer / test if any decimal number is even or odd

inp2 = input("Please enter a number: ")

the_number = str(inp2)

if "." in the_number:
    if int(the_number) % 1 == 0
        if int(the_number) % 2 == 0:
            print("Your number is even.")
        else:
            print("Your number is odd.")
    else:
        print("You dum-dum, that's not an integer.")
else:
    the_number = int(inp2)
    if the_number % 2 == 0:
        print("Your number is even.")
    else:
        print("Your number is odd.")
```

I'm just starting with python so I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: **Recommendation**: Rather than converting your numeric values to strings and testing for a decimal, use the ‘isinstance()’ function.  For examples: isinstance(1, int) or isinstance(1.1, float).  This function returns a boolean value which can be used in your if statements.

Comment: Additionally, your ‘You dum-dum’ print statement should fire **on every occurrence** passing the first if statement, as **all** numeric values containing a decimal are non-integer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on "isinstance()".  In the case of my sub-optimal code, I think my 'dum-dum' statement shouldn't fire one every numeric value containing a decimal, as you could enter "3.0" and receive "You dum-dum..." Let me know if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include a colon at the end of second if statement, like you did in your other conditional statements.

```
if int(the_number) % 1 == 0:
```

Next time, give a closer look at the error message. It'll give you enough hints to fix it yourself, and that's the best way to learn a language.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know this question could not be more beginner-ish so I appreciate your time to type out a response, especially about checking error messages.

Answer (score 1):

EOL.

You forgot a `:`. Line 8 should read `if int(the_number) % 1 == 0:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the : at the end of the if statement
if int(the_number) % 1 == 0:

Answer (score 0):

You can test your input as following code snippet

```
num = input('Enter a number: ')

if num.isnumeric():
    print('You have entered {}'.format(num))
    num = int(num)
    if num%2:
        print('{} is odd number'.format(num))
    else:
        print('{} is even number'.format(num))
else:
    print('Input is not integer number')
```